# Adding CSV data to UK shapefile output area file

Tags: qgis, shapefile, csv, demography

I'm trying to map some demographic data I have in a CSV. It's some demographic data based on mosaic codes. It helpfully has OA codes in one column, which match against the OA codes in my Office for National Statistics (ONS) output area shapefile.

I can add in the shapefile OK to bring up the map with the boundaries I want in, but how do I add in data from the CSV file to produce what I'm after?

Answer (score 4):

Use [Join attributes by field value](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisjoinattributestable):

> Takes an input vector layer and creates a new vector layer that is an
> extended version of the input one, with additional attributes in its
> attribute table.
>
> The additional attributes and their values are taken from a second
> vector layer. An attribute is selected in each of them to define the
> join criteria.

Comment: Thank you, and how do I do that exactly? I can't seem to replicate what you're saying

Comment: Add the layers to your map, Ctrl+Alt+T, search for the tool, follow the instructions